# Do I need to file taxes if my capital gains are less than 4000?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am 55 years old. I'm a dependent of my daughter who's fully supporting me. Just for fun.......I also did some part time job and and played with stock and crypto in 2019:

1) Part time job: $2,000 total for the 2019 year

2) Stock and crypto. I bought some in the amount of $500 and sold it for around $1,200, i.e. $700 short term capital gain.

**So my total earnings for the year 2019 were: $2,000 wages plus $700 short term capital gain. TOTAL: $2,700.**

Should I pay taxes from those short term capital gains? Or should my daughter pay taxes from my capital gains?  Or no taxes since it's less than 4000. I know the 4000 limit rule applies to normal wages. But does it also apply for income from short term capital gains?

Comment: Did they withhold any federal, state or local income taxes from your part time job?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question you are dependent, under age 65 and I am assuming not blind. Your earned income is $2,000 and your unearned income is $700 with a gross income of $2,700

So from [IRS pub 501](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p501.pdf)

> Single dependents—Were you either age 65 or older or blind?
>
> **No.** You must file a return if any of the following apply:
>
> 1. Your unearned income was more than $1,100.
> 2. Your earned income was more than $12,200.
> 3. Your gross income was more than the larger of:
>
>    a. $1,100, or
>      b. Your earned income (up to $11,850) plus $350.
>
> **Yes.** You must file a return if any of the following apply.
>
> 1. Your unearned income was more than $2,750 ($4,400 if 65 or older and blind).
> 2. Your earned income was more than $13,850 ($15,500 if 65 or older and blind).
> 3. Your gross income was more than the larger of:
>
>    a. $2,750 ($4,400 if 65 or older and blind), or
>      b. Your earned income (up to $11,850) plus $2,000 ($3,650 if 65 or older and
>      blind).

So you would be in the no section, and your gross income would be larger than $1,100.

Of course if any income taxes were withheld from the part time job then you would have wanted to file even if not required just to get the taxes refunded.

Comment: Your gross income was more than the larger of:
b. Your earned income (up to $11,850) plus $350.   Doesn't that one catch them? Gross 2700, earned 2000.